# Grafana showing k8s pods down for a minute

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

while using grafana for monitoring with Prometheus, we saw that sometimes grafana showed no pods for a service but when I checked in the cluster, all pods are running without any issue.

This issue is not continuous. Now I have to find out why grafana is alerting? But I don't know where to start.

[image]

Pls, ask if any info needed and pls show me the path, where I can start investigating.

#### Other info

This cluster is AWS EKS. Using `prometheus:v2.22.1`. Deployment of Prometheus & EKS cluster is done by Terraform.

```sh
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:48:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.20-eks-8c49e2", GitCommit:"8c49e2efc3cfbb7788a58025e679787daed22018", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-10-17T05:13:46Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
WARNING: version difference between client (1.22) and server (1.18) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Comment: Please share more details about environment used: kubernetes version? type of instance: managed in cloud (e.g. gcp gke) or self-hosted? Which prometheus version is used? How it was installed? Do you see any patterns when it happens?

Comment: Hi @moonkotte, Added information. There is no pattern. It is happening any time since last week.

Comment: Thank you for response. Was anything changed since last week? Also I can see you're using relatively outdated server version.

Comment: The hole in the graph means the absence of data. The likely cause is that Prometheus for some reason was unable to scrape the metric from that instance at that time. There are infinite number of reasons why something like that can happen. I suggest enabling debug logging in Prometheus and checking the log once it happens again.